# Generate Word file in PHPWord in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpword

I am beginner in Laravel and I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.

I have function to generate PDF file:

```
public function getCalendar(Request $request)
{
        $month = $request->input('month');

        if ($month == null) {
            $now = Carbon::now();
            $month =  $now->month;
        }

        $events = $this->frontendGateway->getEventCalendarDownload($request, $month);
        $logo = public_path('assets/images/logo3.jpg');

        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('prints.events-view', ['events' => $events, 'logo' => $logo]);
        $pdf->setOptions(['isPhpEnabled' => true, 'dpi' => 150, 'setIsRemoteEnabled' => true]);
        $pdf->setPaper('A4', 'letter');
        return $pdf->download('Event Calendar' .  '-' . now()->toDateString() . '.pdf');
    }
```

My Blade:

```
<div id="header" class="fontSize14">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="width: 20%;">
                <img src="{{ $logo }}" class="logo" />
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width: 80%;">
                <span class="fontSize19"><b>My name</b></span><br />
                street<br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="content" class="fontSize11">
    <b class="fontSize19">Calendar</b><br /><br />


    <table width="100%">
        <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Godzina</th>
                <th>Nazwa imprezy</th>
                <th>Miejsce</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($events as $event)
            @php
                $hourFromX = explode(":", $event->hour_from);
                $hourToX = explode(":", $event->hour_to);
                $hourFrom = $hourFromX['0'].":".$hourFromX['1'];
                $hourTo = $hourToX['0'].":".$hourToX['1'];
            @endphp
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
            <td>{{ $event->date_from }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ $hourFrom }}-{{ $hourTo }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ $event->title }}</td>
            <td align="left">@if(isset($event->localization)) {{ $event->localization->name }},
                {{ $event->localization->city }}
                {{ $event->localization->street }} @endif</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div><div id="header" class="fontSize14">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="width: 20%;">
                <img src="{{ $logo }}" class="logo" />
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="width: 80%;">
                <span class="fontSize19"><b>My name</b></span><br />
                street name
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="content" class="fontSize11">
    <b class="fontSize19">Kalendarz wydarzeń</b><br /><br />


    <table width="100%">
        <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Godzina</th>
                <th>Nazwa imprezy</th>
                <th>Miejsce</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($events as $event)
            @php
                $hourFromX = explode(":", $event->hour_from);
                $hourToX = explode(":", $event->hour_to);
                $hourFrom = $hourFromX['0'].":".$hourFromX['1'];
                $hourTo = $hourToX['0'].":".$hourToX['1'];
            @endphp
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
            <td>{{ $event->date_from }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ $hourFrom }}-{{ $hourTo }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ $event->title }}</td>
            <td align="left">@if(isset($event->localization)) {{ $event->localization->name }},
                {{ $event->localization->city }}
                {{ $event->localization->street }} @endif</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

It's work fine.

Now I want make generate Word file.
I found this lib: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

I try change my function to this lib (export to Word file):

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
....

```
public function getCalendar(Request $request)
    {
        $month = $request->input('month');
        if ($month == null) {
            $now = Carbon::now();
            $month =  $now->month;
        }
        $events = $this->frontendGateway->getEventCalendarDownload($request, $month);
        $logo = public_path('assets/images/logo3.jpg');
...
    }
```

How can I add my data and view to Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the view you have you need to render and assign to a variable:

```
$view_content = View::make('prints.events-view', ['events' => $events, 'logo' => $logo])->render();
```

then create a word document by this library and append to content to

```
// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

 // Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText($view_content);

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$file_name = 'event_calendar_' .  '-' . now()->toDateString() . '.doc';

$objWriter->save(public_path($file_name));
```

and then the URL of the file will be url($file_name)

Comment: thank you. This code return me error: mkdir(): Permission denied. I need auto-download file

Comment: I added more details to the reply basically it's up to you to decide where to save the files and how to serve it :),

Comment: Thank you. Now I have problem with Corrupt Word File. I can't open it :(

Comment: what are you getting ?

Comment: I am facing same problem too. The word file is corrupt